# Git-Branch status

Tags: bash, git

In my `.bashrc` file, I have those two blocks :

1-

```
# get current branch in git repo
function parse_git_branch() {
    BRANCH=`git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
    if [ ! "${BRANCH}" == "" ]
    then
        STAT=`parse_git_dirty`
        echo "[${BRANCH}${STAT}]"
    else
        echo ""
    fi
}
```

2-

```
# Prompt
if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then
    export PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]┌─╼ \[$(tput setaf 7)\][\w]\n\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\$(if [[ \$? == 0 ]]; then echo \"\[$(tput setaf 1)\]└────╼ \[$(tput setaf 7)\][ssh]\"; else echo \"\[$(tput setaf 1)\]└╼ \[$(tput setaf 7)\][ssh]\"; fi) \[$(tput setaf 7)\]"
else
    export PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]┌─╼ \[$(tput setaf 7)\][\w]\n\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\$(if [[ \$? == 0 ]]; then echo \"\[$(tput setaf 1)\]└────╼\"; else echo \"\[$(tput setaf 1)\]└╼\"; fi) \[$(tput setaf 7)\]"
fi
```

which give me the following result

[image: [bash prompt image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcTWP.png)

I would like to insert `parse_git_branch` in such a way I could see on which git-branch I am. How could I modify the second block so that it works? Where do I have to put `\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]` in the second block?

Comment: The standard way to do this is to use [git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh).

Comment: I could, but that would leave you with nothing to learn.  So I won't.